# How to create a dynamically bound panorama page with wide items using Caliburn Micro?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, caliburn.micro, panorama-control

Inspired by some great apps out there, I want to have a `PanoramaItem` in my Panorama, that is wider than the standard width of the `PanoramaItem`.

See the item with tiles in LinkedIn's app:

[image]

Normally this is achieved in xaml by adding a `PanoramaItem` with a predefined width:

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Width="555">
```

But, I would like to avoid hardcoding my UIs this way, as the application is Caliburn-Micro based, and the Panorama control is data-bound using handy Caliburn conventions. The view model behind it is a Conductor, and pages are injected into it. The `Panorama` control is bound to the `Items` property of the view model.

My problem is that if one of the items, or screens, is wider than the standard width of the panorama item, it gets clipped.

I tried solving it by specifying ItemTemplate:

```
<controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
```

but that did not change a thing.

How would one solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the question is that apparently you can not. I tried overriding `OnViewAttached`, finding the parent of my dynamically bound control (`ContentControl`), but I was not able to retrieve its parent ( the `PanoramaItem` I wanted to make wider).

So after much trial end error I settled on the following solution:

I define my panorama items explicitly in XAML:

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="item1">
    <ContentControl x:Name="Control1"/>
</controls:PanoramaItem>
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="Wide Item" Width="700" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ContentControl x:Name="WideControl"/>
</controls:PanoramaItem>
```

They are also injected into the ViewModel and added to the collection of `Items`, inherited from Caliburn's `Cunductor`.

Then, I need to make sure that the ViewModel knows about the currently selected item, so the associated view can be activated by CaliburnMicro:

```
<controls:Panorama  Name="MainPanorama" 
    cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = 
    [Action  MainPanorama_OnSelectionChanged($eventArgs)]" 
    SelectedIndex="{Binding ActivePage, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

I also make sure that the ViewModel receives the `SelectionChanged` event, so it knows when to activate the currently visible item.

And finally the trick that makes it all work in ViewModel:

```
public void MainPanorama_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ActivateItem(Items[ActivePage]);
}
```